# How can I get custom icons to resize according to the zoom level on a map?

Tags: r, leaflet

Using the `leaflet` package, I have created a custom icon that I use across a map.

The orange points denote where an event occurs, and the white custom icons denote where those events ended.

At a zoomed-out level, the custom icons are perfectly sized, but the trouble is that when I zoom in, the custom icons remain the same size, with the other plotted points growing considerably around them.

Is there a way to adjust the size of the icons to match the zoom level on the map?

**Full-view:**
[image]

**Zoomed-in view: (icons are tiny (remaining the same size as the full-view), in the middle of the orange points)**
[image]

**My current code**

```
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet(geochats) %>%
  addTiles('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',attribution='Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>') %>% 
  addCircles(~jitter(origin_lon), ~jitter(origin_lat), popup = geochats$origin_city, weight = 1, radius = 20, 
             color = "#EA7437", stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 0.5) %>% 
  addMarkers(~jitter(end_lon), ~jitter(end_lat), icon = JS("L.icon({iconUrl = 'G:\\My Drive\\Images\\icLogoWhite@1x.svg', iconSize: [10, 10], map.on('zoomend', function() { })), popup = geochats$end_city))}"))
m  # Print the map
```